# image toggle button can not move in a scroll view

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml

I am developing a blackberry app. I am using a toggle button on scrollview but scrollview cannot move Vertical or Horizontal.

When we use a simple button on a scroll view then scrollview move on both sides.

```
ScrollView 
{ 
   preferredWidth: 768
   Container 
   {
      layout: StackLayout 
      {
         orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight 
      }

      ImageToggleButton 
      { 
         imageSourceDefault: "asset:///search/activites_hover.png"
         imageSourceChecked: "asset:///search/drop-down.png" 
      } 
   } 
   scrollViewProperties
   { 
      scrollMode: ScrollMode.Both 
   } 
}
```

Comment: ScrollView {
            preferredWidth: 768
            Container {
                layout: StackLayout {
                    orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
                }
                ImageToggleButton {                   
                    imageSourceDefault: "asset:///search/activites_hover.png"
                    imageSourceChecked: "asset:///search/drop-down.png"                                
                }            
            }
            scrollViewProperties{
                scrollMode: ScrollMode.Both
            }
        }